# How to quickly obtain PHP localised ordinals using Zend_Locale

Tags: php, zend-framework, ordinal

I need to localise ordinal values i.e 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.. into various european languages There doesn't seem to be an option for doing this with Zend_Locale. Anyone know of a way of doing this in 5.2.x without the intl pecl extension?

To be clear, 5.3 is not an option and installing an additional extension may not be either. Anyone know of a way of doing this using Zend_Locale?

thanks!

codecowboy

Comment: your best option would probably be Zend_Translate using the array adapter

Comment: I agree I've been hunting around for a solution here and kept coming back to Zend_Translate.

Comment: I also think that is the best solution, since it's not supported by zend_locale as you mentioned before. Actually I also think this is rather a "translation" issue instead of a localization issue...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to connect to Google translate using Zend_GData, more info on the API; http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/gtt/

Don't forget to save or cache the responses requested.